# CSV DictWriter cannot write to file open in binary mode, BigQuery Client cannot upload file read in text mode

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery

Using Python 3.10 with `google-cloud-bigquery==3.4.2`.

I have CSV data that I need to load, transform and upload to BigQuery. I want to use a `SpooledTemporaryFile` for the intermediate data to avoid disk I/O. Simplified code:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client, LoadJobConfig, SourceFormat

csv_lines = ["A;2;3", "B;4;6", "C;8;12"]
fieldnames = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
csv_reader = DictReader(csv_lines, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=";")
with SpooledTemporaryFile(mode="w+") as tmp:
    writer = DictWriter(tmp, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in csv_reader:
        writer.writerow({"Foo": row["Foo"], "Bar": row["Bar"], "Baz": row["Baz"]})

    job = Client().load_table_from_file(
        tmp,
        "GCP_PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID.BIGQUERY_TABLE_ID",
        job_config=LoadJobConfig(
            source_format=SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=0, autodetect=True
        ),
    )
    job.result()
```

The problem is that if I open the `SpooledTemporaryFile` with `mode="w+b"` (the default), `DictWriter` fails:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

And if I use `mode="w+"`, the `DictWriter` writes but the GCP upload job fails with

```
ValueError: Cannot upload files opened in text mode:
  use open(filename, mode='rb') or open(filename, mode='r+b')
```

Any ideas on how to solve this Gordian knot welcome.

Comment: Aren't you still writing to disk as you have NOT specified any max_size (default 0) in SpooledTemporaryFile

Comment: Good catch, I thought the default was "unlimited until OOM" but upon reading the docs again, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

open the file in wb mode

and wrap it in io.TextIOwrapper

```
with SpooledTemporaryFile(mode="w+b") as tmp:
    with io.TextIOWrapper(tmp, encoding='utf-8') as txtwrap:
        writer = DictWriter(txtwrap, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        for row in csv_reader:
            writer.writerow({"Foo": row["Foo"], "Bar": row["Bar"], "Baz": row["Baz"]})
    tmp.seek(0)
    job = Client().load_table_from_file(
        tmp,
        "GCP_PROJECT_ID.BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID.BIGQUERY_TABLE_ID",
    job_config=LoadJobConfig(
            source_format=SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=0, autodetect=True
        ),
    )
    job.result()
```

adjust as you need

dont forget to import io

you might want to specify a max_size in SpooledTemporaryFile if you want it not to write to disk and spool in memory
max_size=

```
with SpooledTemporaryFile(mode="w+b",max_size=100000000) as tmp:
```

Comment: Looks promising, but no cigar. After updating to Python 3.11 to circumvent [this issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70363) I'm still getting `ValueError: Cannot upload files opened in text mode` for both `mode="w+b"` and `"wb"`. It seems like the `TextIOWrapper` changes the file open mode.

Comment: Scratch that, after dropping into pdb I could confirm the file mode is unchanged (`wb`) - it's just the error message from the BigQuery client that is badly worded. Then I tried with `r+b` (for which I understand the only difference from `w+b` is that it doesn't truncate the file first, which is irrelevant for temp files) but got another error from the BQ client: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` Apparently, I'll have to create a temp file on disk before the BQ client will stoop to uploading it. :(

Comment: temp file exists only in the context of the with loop...you exit means you close it. and it's gone. you will have to use good old open without for loop ..and after writing the file use  tmp.seek(0) to set position of file handle to beginning of the file so that it can be read from beginning and not truncated to current position after writing. and yes it has to be w+b not wb

Comment: Also tmp.seek(0) and subsequent code is within outer with loop and outside inner textiowrapper loop

Comment: Calling `.seek(0)` on tmp after using `TextIOWriter` also raises `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. And I can't close and re-open, because a `SpooledTemporaryFile` is destroyed on close.

Comment: you will have to call .seek(0) within the outer with loop...the file is open till you exit the `with SpooledTemporaryFile`. i am not sure if the indenation of that seek(0) is visible. its  within the `with SpooledTemporaryFile(mode="w+b") as tmp:`  not outside

Comment: Indeed: https://gist.github.com/kthy/454887fb4c6c6a97b67f5729e5376ce7 fails with `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`